# Create an error log after submiting my app in windows phone store

Tags: windows-phone-8, logging, count, crash, store

I am new in windows phone app development.

After I submitting my xap file in windows store, I noticed some more crash count in the dashboard and i am not able to find how my app got crashed.

Please help me to create and access the error log in my windows phone app.
thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Dev Center, go to the `Crash count` view and click on the number of crashes next to your app name. It will redirect you to a detail view of crashes of your app (the url is https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/CrashReport?applicationId={your app guid}. There, click `Export top stack traces from the last 30 days`.

If this is not enough (and rarely is), you have to implement logging your self or use a 3rd party service like Crittericism, BugSense, etc.